# PostBack Option Not Working | ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working something in Visual Web Developer 2008 Exrepss Edition.

I have 2 aspx file, Default.aspx and Default2.aspx

In Defauly.aspx  Design View i have one button, in her properties on option "PostBack URL" i choose Default2.aspx

When i run site and click on Button do not open Default2.aspx?

Can you help me!
Thanks

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Can you show you code as an example?

Comment: I noticed when i click on PostBackURL option, in Source Code VIEW do not add any code in my Button?
Which code to add in BUtton, to open Default2.aspx from Default.aspx

PS. i dont have any error message, because comamnd post back dont work anything

Comment: This is code 
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Default3.aspx" 
        Text="Button" />

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by click event of the button

```
      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default3.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that "UseSubmitBehavior" property for the button is set to true.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Default2.aspx" 
        Text="Button" />

Comment: ok, please  sure the application is running and there are no items on the page that prevent the submit action like validators.